# Sharp AR-6020 printer not working

Tags: printing

I recently installed a Sharp AR-6020 printer on my Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS system using the PPD file provided on the official Sharp website. However, when I attempt to print, nothing happens, and I receive a notification indicating that the job is complete. I also attempted to install the printer through CUPS, but encountered the same issue.

Any insights or solutions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: try adding by settings>printers

Comment: you have not mentioned which Linux version/distro you are using. Impossible to help without such vital information. Read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have updated my problem. Hope it may help to understand. @graham

Comment: Looking at the Sharp site, I don't see a Linux driver for the Sharp AR-6020 on;ly windoze. Where di you get the driver from and have you approached Sharp support for advice?

Comment: from below website. There is a 'Software and Driver' option:
https://www.sharp.eu/ar-6020
@graham